# react native define props type

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-props

I don't know '<'Props'>'. Finding to use props, i found to use another props
Why Props is to use "type" and '<'Props'>'? What's mean? 
Please answer my questions

```
type Props = {};
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>To get started, edit App.js</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>{instructions}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the  syntax came from 'flow'.

Flow is a static type checker for javascript for more information visit

https://flow.org/en/docs/react/components/

Answer (score 0):

You can delete `type Props = {};` and then delete `'props'` inside the `Component<Props>`,then start your coding